# TkInter: how to display the normal cursor?

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse-cursor

I have a simple TkInter interface where, after a button click, the cursor of the mouse is changed to ***fleur***. Now, after the task using this cursor is done, I want to use a normal cursor.  By normal I mean the cursor you see now on your own computer.

I checked the list of available cursors [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/cursors.html) but no one of them looks normal.

Is there any way to set back the mouse pointer to a normal cursor ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To go back to the standard cursor, pass an empty string to `cursor`:

```
root.config(cursor='')
```

For example:

```
from Tkinter import *

def cursor():
    if not root.cget('cursor') == '':
        root.config(cursor='')
    else:
        root.config(cursor='fleur')

root = Tk()
Button(root, text='Change cursor', command=cursor).pack()
root.mainloop()
```